# Bitmap Frame Limit

Tags: c#, memory, bitmap, overloading

I'm developing a screen recording program and I've run into what I *think* is a memory issue.

My code is the following:

```
public void RecordTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    screenBounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;

    lastFrame = new Bitmap(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);

    Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(lastFrame);
    graphics.CopyFromScreen(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.X,
                    SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Y,
                    0,
                    0,
                    SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Size,
                    CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);

    recordedFrames.Add(lastFrame);
}
```

What happens is that, after about 100 frames have been recorded, I get an error in either

```
lastFrame = new Bitmap(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);
```

or in

```
Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(lastFrame);
graphics.CopyFromScreen(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.X,
                SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Y,
                0,
                0,
                SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Size,
                CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
```

That tells me that one of my parameters is invalid.

I noticed that when I change the bitmap's pixel format from 32 to 24, it gets to about 120 frames before crashing.

*Edit*
 -- Thank you for informing me about the `using` statement, that was very useful and fixed the problem with memory overload.

I should have noted earlier that I am using a library called [AforgeNet](http://www.aforgenet.com/framework/docs/), and that now I am getting an error when trying to add a frame to a video writer.

The error is: `An unhandled exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in AForge.Video.FFMPEG.dll

Additional information: The provided bitmap must be 24 or 32 bpp color image or 8 bpp grayscale image.`

Here is my code for recording frames:

```
public void RecordTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        screenBounds = Screen.PrimaryScreen.Bounds;

        // lastFrame = new Bitmap(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb);

        using (Bitmap lastFrame = new Bitmap(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Width, SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Height, System.Drawing.Imaging.PixelFormat.Format32bppRgb))
        {
            using (Graphics graphics = Graphics.FromImage(lastFrame))
            {
                graphics.CopyFromScreen(SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.X,
                                SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Y,
                                0,
                                0,
                                SystemInformation.VirtualScreen.Size,
                                CopyPixelOperation.SourceCopy);
            }

            recordedFrames.Add(lastFrame);
        }
    }
```

And here is my code for adding frames to the video writer, which happens *after* I record all frames:

```
public void Button_StopRecording_OnClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (recording == true)
        {
            recording = false;
            recordTimer.Stop();

            // Write all of the recorded frames to the video.
            foreach (Bitmap frame in recordedFrames)
            {
                videoWriter.WriteVideoFrame(frame);
            }

            // Then, close the video writer.
            videoWriter.Close();

            // Empty the list of recorded frames.
            recordedFrames.Clear();

            Text = "Screen Recorder";
        }
    }
```

Thanks again!

Comment: Can you post the exact error message and any inner exceptions that it may have?

Comment: Do you dispose bitmaps somewhere? This could be an out of memory problem. Note that each bitmap can allocate around two megabytes of memory, depending on screen resolution and bit depth.

Comment: I don't see a single `using` or `.Dispose()`. You really need to do one or the other because a lot of your objects are using unmanaged resources.

Comment: As noted you need to `Dispose` of all `GDI` objects when you are done with them; this includes the `Bitmaps` and `Graphics` objects you keep creating..!

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".